# Calculate cumulative sum from last non-zero entry in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, cumsum

I have a numeric series like [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0]. I would like to calculate the numeric sum from the last non-zero values. i.e the cumsum will be reset to zero once a zero entry occurs.

```
input: [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0]
output:[0,0,0,0,1,2,3,0,0,1,2,0]
```

Is there a built-in python function able to achieve this? Or better way to calculate it without loop?

Comment: Can you use numpy?

Comment: yes, do numpy and pandas have any function related?

Answer (score 9):

You can do it with [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate). In addition to passing an iterable as the first argument, it accepts an optional 2nd argument that should be a 2 argument function where the first argument is the accumulated result and the second argument is the current element from the iterable. You can pass a fairly simple lambda as the optional 2nd argument to calculate the running total unless the current element is zero.

```
from itertools import accumulate

nums = [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0]

result = accumulate(nums, lambda acc, elem: acc + elem if elem else 0)
print(list(result))
# [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0]
```

Comment: thanks for your quick response. perfect! btw, can accumulate function be used on dataframe? Say, I have a matrix, where each column is a numeric series. I would like to calculate the cumsum for each column.

Comment: @AAA sure, `itertools.accumulate` will accept any iterable, so lots of ways to use with a dataframe, series, etc.

Answer (score 1):

We can do this in numpy with two passes of `np.cumsum(..)`. First we calculate the `cumsum` of the array:

```
a = np.array([0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0])
c = np.cumsum(a)
```

This gives us:

```
>>> c
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5])
```

Next we filter `a` on elements where the value is `0` and we elementwise calculate the difference between that element and its predecessor:

```
corr = np.diff(np.hstack(((0,), c[a == 0])))
```

then this is the correction we need to apply on those elements:

```
>>> corr
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 2])
```

We can then make a copy of `a` (or do this inplace), and subtract the correction:

```
a2 = a.copy()
a2[a == 0] -= corr
```

this gives us:

```
>>> a2
array([ 0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1, -3,  0,  1,  1, -2])
```

and now we can calculate the cummulative sum of `a2` that will reset to `0` for an `0`, since the correction keeps track of the increments in between:

```
>>> a2.cumsum()
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0])
```

or as a function:

```
import numpy as np

def cumsumreset(iterable, reset=0):
    a = np.array(iterable)
    c = a.cumsum()
    a2 = a.copy()
    filter = a == reset
    a2[filter] -= np.diff(np.hstack(((0,), c[filter])))
    return a2.cumsum()
```

this then gives us:

```
>>> cumsumreset([0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0])
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0])
```